# How to convert %p to %d in cpp?

Tags: c++, pointers, hex

I have this following function

```
VOID printip(void *ip, THREADID tid)
{ 
   PIN_GetLock(&pinLock, tid+1);
   fprintf(trace, "%d %p\n", tid, ip);
   fflush(trace);
   PIN_ReleaseLock(&pinLock);
}
```

The pointer ip is printed in hexadecimal format, but I want to print it in integer format. So i tried the following-->

```
VOID printip(int *ip, THREADID tid)
{ 
   PIN_GetLock(&pinLock, tid+1);
   fprintf(trace, "%d %d\n", tid, ip);
   fflush(trace);
   PIN_ReleaseLock(&pinLock);
}
```

but it is giving me this error.
[image]

Please suggest how to print it as integer?

Comment: Please post error messages as text, not as image.

Comment: Just cast: `(int)tid`??

Comment: @kebs what is the problem with image?

Comment: btw guys, problem is solved. I have just used " long int x=*((long int *) &ip)" and printed %d of x.

Comment: @RohanShaw that is the wrong way to handle this. That will fail on systems where `sizeof(long int) < sizeof(int*)`. Use `reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(ip)` instead.

Comment: @t.niese I'm not sure I get the comment that you tagged me with. Do you agree that posting error messages as image is a bad idea or not? I read your comment as "yes" but if so, I don't get why you tagged me?

Comment: @RohanShaw  the contents of an image cannot be copied and persons with a visual handicap might have problems reading it. The purpose of a Q&A platform like StackOverflow is to not only help you with your problem but anyone else having the same problem in the future.

Comment: @kebs tagged you by accident should have been RohanShaw.

Answer (score 3):

`#include <cinttypes>` then use the [fixed width (decimal) format](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) for `uintptr_t`.

```
  printf("%d %" PRIuPTR "\n", tid, (uintptr_t)ip);
```

Using `"%d"` and casting the pointer to `int` will fail when pointers are not the same size as integers, for example in 64-bit compiles on x86_64 with (most) compilers where `sizeof(int) == 4` but `sizeof(void *) == 8`.

Comment: Okkk.. Thank you. :)